# Instantiating ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on an assignment that has me, among other things, do this:

Add member variable of Data type ArrayList to represent the two teams of the game, then write method createTeams() that Instantiates the member variable of type ArrayList, and Instantiates two instances of class Team.

This is how I have done that:

```
private ArrayList<Team> Teams;

public void createTeams(){
    ArrayList<Team> TeamOne = new ArrayList<Team>();
    ArrayList<Team> TeamTwo = new ArrayList<Team>();
}
```

However, netbeans response to this has made me wonder, what are the differences between these three blocks of code?

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

-

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne;
```

-

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne;
TeamOne = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: The first one is just doing all you want in one go instead of separating it over different lines. You can remove *Team* from <> after *new*.

Comment: Nothing. However your reference variable should be the `List` interface. Not the implementation which is `ArrayList`

Comment: [What is the difference between declaration and definition in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11715485)

Comment: If they are supposed to be member (instance) variables, why aren't `TeamOne` and `TeamTwo` fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne = new ArrayList<Team>();
```

Declares a variable of type ArrayList, named TeamOne and assigns value to it;

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne;
```

just declares the variable/reference;

```
ArrayList<Team> TeamOne; //declares the reference
TeamOne = new ArrayList<>(); //assigns value to it
```

First one is referred to as "in-line initialization".

Two observations:

- declare your reference types as the interface, not the implementation. In your case List
- use lower cased camel case naming convention for variables

Following those suggestions your code will look like:

```
private List<Team> teams;

public void createTeams(){
    List<Team> teamOne = new ArrayList<Team>();
    List<Team> teamTwo = new ArrayList<Team>();
}
```

Comment: You could remove the type in the diamond operator too.

Comment: That is true, but it's a syntax sugar - you should use it when you know what it's doing and I think for this particular question - it's too early for that.

Answer (score 0):

First line it's declaring and instantiating in a single line of code the TeamOne object.
The second line it's only declaring, but not instantiating the TeamOne object.
The third line (the last one) declaring in the first line the  TeamOne object and after that on the second line it's instantiating the TeamOne object.